# Swift 3 How to set different background color when selected cell in collectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have two Button and one `collectionView` in `viewcontroller`. When I selected Button one and selected one of cell, it looks like this:

[image]

and when I selected Button two it looks like this:

[image]

So my problem is when I selected back Button one and the `collectionView`, it should be like the first image.

What should I do so I can get that? Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should custom your CollectionViewCell and add ***mark*** attribute in that Cell.

When you tap button one that cell. Set value of attribute ***mark = true.***

When you tap button one again you just need to test ***mark*** attribute to set cell's background color

to refresh CollectionView (update layout). use

```
collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```

Answer (score 0):

Without really seeing any code, I would assume you need to set the background color of cell in viewDidAppear and not viewDidLoad. The reason why is because viewDidLoad only gets called once and if you are hitting the Back Button from the navigation controller and its not setting the color as intended that would be the first step to see if it works like you need.